# Defining variable using value of another variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to get Python to define two integer variables, numberone and numbertwo, with the first being between 1 and 100 and the second being less than the first.

I have tried this code:

```
    numberone=random.randint(0,100)  
    numbertwo=random.randint(0,numberone)
```

but the second number is occasionally larger than the first.

Am I missing something completely obvious? :s

Comment: When is it larger? It can be the same number, but never larger. Could you be mixing the variables at some point?

Comment: They can be the same. If you want it to be always smaller, use `randint(1, 100)` and `randint(0, numberone - 1)` respectively.

Comment: Do you ever redefine the first number in between?

Comment: That is a direct section of code (there is nothing in between) @MalikBrahimi

Comment: That is the only point at which the variables are defined, and they are fed back in that order (numberone then numbertwo) @Zizouz212

Comment: Try this for me: `a = random.randint(0, 100)` and on the next line `range(a + 1)`. Do you ever get a number that is outside what is outputted by range?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing "greater than" and "not less than" - is not possible for the `numbertwo > numberone` but it might very well be that `numbertwo == numberone`, which also means that `numbertwo < numberone` is false.

---

[`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) is a bit confusing in that unlike `range(a, b)` which includes numbers up to `b - 1` only, `randint` might produce `b`. To get the "including `a` but excluding  `b` behaviour, use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

```
numberone = random.randint(0, 100)   # 0 .. 100
numbertwo = random.randrange(0, numberone)   # 0 .. numberone - 1
```

Comment: I'm still getting the fault using random.randrange(0, numberone) i'm afraid! :(

Comment: Moreover, provide sample numbers for cases of failure.